# Extract Translation and Rotation from Fundamental Matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, rotation, translation

I am trying to retrieve translation and rotation vectors from a computed fundamental Matrix. I do use OpenCV and the general approach is from wikipedia. My Code is like this:

```
//Compute Essential Matrix
Mat A = cameraMatrix(); //Computed using chessboard
Mat F = fundamentalMatrix(); //Computed using matching keypoints
Mat E = A.t() * F * A;

//Perfrom SVD on E
SVD decomp = SVD(E);

//U
Mat U = decomp.u;

//S
Mat S(3, 3, CV_64F, Scalar(0));
S.at<double>(0, 0) = decomp.w.at<double>(0, 0);
S.at<double>(1, 1) = decomp.w.at<double>(0, 1);
S.at<double>(2, 2) = decomp.w.at<double>(0, 2);

//V
Mat V = decomp.vt; //Needs to be decomp.vt.t(); (transpose once more)

//W
Mat W(3, 3, CV_64F, Scalar(0));
W.at<double>(0, 1) = -1;
W.at<double>(1, 0) = 1;
W.at<double>(2, 2) = 1;

cout << "computed rotation: " << endl;
cout << U * W.t() * V.t() << endl;
cout << "real rotation:" << endl;
Mat rot;
Rodrigues(images[1].rvec - images[0].rvec, rot); //Difference between known rotations
cout << rot << endl;
```

At the end I try to compare the estimated rotation to the one I computed using the chessboard which is in every Image (I plan to get the extrinsic parameters without the chessboard). For example I get this:

```
computed rotation:
[0.8543027125286542, -0.382437675069228, 0.352006107978011;
  0.3969758209413922, 0.9172325022900715, 0.03308676972148356;
  0.3355250705298953, -0.1114717965690797, -0.9354127247453767]

real rotation:
[0.9998572365450219, 0.01122579241510944, 0.01262886032882241;
  -0.0114034800333517, 0.9998357441946927, 0.01408706050863871;
  -0.01246864754818991, -0.01422906234781374, 0.9998210172891051]
```

So clearly there seems to be a problem, I just can't figure out what it could be.

EDIT:
Here are the results I got with the untransposed vt(obviously from another scene):

```
computed rotation: 
[0.8720599858028177, -0.1867080200550876, 0.4523842353671251;
 0.141182538980452, 0.9810442195058469, 0.1327393312518831;
-0.4685924368239661, -0.05188790438313154, 0.8818893204535954]
real rotation
[0.8670861432556456, -0.427294988334106, 0.2560871201732064;
 0.4024551137989086, 0.9038194629873437, 0.1453969040329854;
-0.2935838918455123, -0.02300806966752995, 0.9556563855167906]
```

Here is my computed camera matrix, the error was pretty low(about 0.17...).

```
[1699.001342509651, 0, 834.2587265398068;
  0, 1696.645251354618, 607.1292618175946;
  0, 0, 1]
```

Here are the results I get when trying to reproject a cube...
Camera 0, the cube is axis-aligned, rotation and translation are (0, 0, 0).
[image http://imageshack.us/a/img802/5292/bildschirmfoto20130110u.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img802/5292/bildschirmfoto20130110u.png)

and the other one, with the epilines of the points in the first image.
[image http://imageshack.us/a/img546/189/bildschirmfoto20130110uy.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img546/189/bildschirmfoto20130110uy.png)

Comment: `decomp.vt` is V transpose, not V. What do you get if you say `U * W.t() * V`?

Comment: Excuse my late answer, thank you for your correction. I had obviously forgotten this one. I updated the answer with the new results, unfortunately they still do not seem exactly right.

Comment: Should the computed distortion Coefficients also be multiplied into the Essential Matrix somehow?

Comment: Could my cameraMatrix be wrong? The formula came from Wikipedia. I added my current matrix to the first post.

Comment: i'm not sure about the details of this algorithm other than from wikipedia, alas. Have you rotated the image with these matrices to see how well it lines up with the original?

Comment: No I did not. How would I do that?

Comment: What I did try was reprojecting a cube on both images based on the computed values. I believe the epilines per vertex should match. But unfortunately they do not. I'll post the code I used later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please take a look at this link:

[DIKU-3DCV2/Handouts/Lecture16.pdf](https://ia601408.us.archive.org/view_archive.php?archive=/7/items/DIKU-3DCV2/DIKU-3DCV2.zip&file=DIKU-3DCV2%2FHandouts%2FLecture16.pdf).

[alternative link](https://archive.org/details/DIKU-3DCV2)

Refer to Page 2. There are two possibilities for R. The first is U*W*VT and the second is U*WT*VT. You used the second. Try the first.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was missing. I can also recommend the very simple and easy to understand sources of the new book "Mastering OpenCV with Practical Computer Vision Projects" https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code

Comment: Can you provide a link explaining how to establish which R is correct?

Comment: Its written in the slides, in my case I just "tested" the four possible solution by applying the matrices to actual points. Maybe you could implement a more efficient test using dot products of the normalized translation vectors and the third columns of each R. To see if they are "facing" the correct directions.

Comment: The link is now dead, even on archive.org. Would someone have a copy or a similar reference ?

Comment: The link is now: http://igt.ip.uca.fr/~ab/Classes/DIKU-3DCV2/Handouts/Lecture16.pdf

Comment: Link is dead again

Comment: @GabrielDevillers the link is dead again.

Answer (score 0):

The 8-point algorithm is the simplest method of computing fundamental matrix, but if care is taken you can perform it well. The key to obtain the good results is proper careful normalization of the input data before constructing the equations to solve. Many of algorithms can do it. 
Pixels point coordinate must be changed to camera coordinates, you do it in this line:

`Mat E = A.t() * F * A;`

However this assumption is not accurate. If camera calibration matrix K is known, then you may apply inverse to the point x to obtain the point expressed in normalized coordinates.

`X_{norm}= K.inv()*X_{pix}` where `X_{pix}(2)`, z is equal 1.

In the case of the 8PA, a simple transformation of points improve and hence in the stability of the results. The suggested normalization is a translation and scaling of each image so that the centroid of the reference points is at origin of the coordinates and the RMS distance of the points from the origin is equal to `\sqrt{2}`. Note that it is recommended that the singularity condition should be enforced before denormalization.

Reference: check it if  :  [you are still interested](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/andrew/scs/cs/15-463/f07/proj_final/www/amichals/fundamental.pdf)