# OpenCV: Rotation Matrix and Translation Vector for a Moving Single Camers

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera-calibration, calibration, extrinsic-parameters

I have a calibrated (intrinsic parameters) camera. Later, I need to use it for taking different photos from an object. They will be used to re-project some points of the images.

A key step is to calculate Rotation matrix and Translation vector, using 2 images of a same object. I am a newbie in image processing and I have no idea how to do that. Any information would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. find feature points in image A
2. find feature points in image B
3. find feature correspondence
4. use [cv::findFundamentalMat](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.5/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=fundamental#cv2.findFundamentalMat) to find the [fundamental matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_matrix_%28computer_vision%29).
5. find the [essential matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_matrix) by E = K'FK where K is the [camera intrinsics parameters matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_resectioning)
6. now for the tricky part (that was asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150152/extract-translation-and-rotation-from-fundamental-matrix)): as suggested by @Majek, use https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code, it will give you a good start.

Comment: Thank you Mercury! I'll try it. It seems to be what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You probable want to look at OpenCV's [calibration](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) functionality. Their [tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/table_of_content_calib3d/table_of_content_calib3d.html#table-of-content-calib3d) on topic will probably also be helpful.