# How to compute rotation-translation matrix between 2 frames with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to compute the rotation-translation matrix [R|t] matrix between 2 frames with `OpenCV` (see http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=fundamentalmat#camera-calibration-and-3d-reconstruction)

I know I have to :

1) Detect features on both frames (with `SURF`, for example),
2) Matche features (with `ORB` and `BFMatcher`, for example),
3) Compute the [R|t] matrix. The intrinsic parameters are known.

However, I don't know how to complete the third step with `OpenCV`. Is there a regular/easy way to do this ?

My aim is to compute the trajectory of a camera.

Comment: Assuming you're dealing with 2D-to-2D correspondences, have you tried `cv::findHomography()`?

Comment: I'm using RGB+D camera, so I know the depth for each pixel.
However, I tried cv::findHomography(), but the result that return seems weird. I'm maybe missing something.. ?

Comment: `findHomography()` takes `vector<Point2f>` source and destination points and finds the 3x3 projective matrix that maps the source onto the destination points. I strongly recommend using the RANSAC method with default arguments for `findHomography()`. Because the points it accepts are 2D, they totally ignore depth. For 2D-to-3D correspondences you will need `solvePnP()` or `solvePnPRANSAC()`, but first you will have to know the actual coordinates of your target in the 3D object's coordinate space.

Comment: Well, with the RGB+D camera, if I suppose that my initial position is (x = 0, y = 0, z = 0) and that z will always stay equal to 0. Which function am I supposed to use ? Is it 2D-to-2D or 2D-to-3D ? That's not clear in my head.
Later, I'll compute the position of each pixel in the real world, but that's the next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use RANSAC to compute either the Fundamental or Essential matrices

OpenCV nicely provides the [`cv::findFundamentalMat`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#Mat%20findFundamentalMat%28InputArray%20points1,%20InputArray%20points2,%20int%20method,%20double%20param1,%20double%20param2,%20OutputArray%20mask%29) function to do so.

Then it is a matter of getting `[R|t]` from both `A`, the intrinsic parameter matrix and `F`, the fundamental matrix. I would refer you to [Extract Translation and Rotation from Fundamental Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150152/extract-translation-and-rotation-from-fundamental-matrix) for more information on that.

Comment: Use a homography matrix, not the fundamental matrix, to estimate pose. The fundamental matrix is scale free and yields bad results.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use stereoCalibrate where your rotation & translation matrices are R & T respectively. object_points, l_image_points, r_image_points coordinates of matched points/features in object and left/right image frames.
stereoCalibrate(object_points, l_image_points, r_image_points, LcameraMatrix, LdistCoeffs, RcameraMatrix, RdistCoeffs, imageSize, R, T, E, F);