# Structure from Motion : Error calculating Rotation and translation matrix from Essential matrix

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, structure-from-motion

I am trying to simulate the structure from motion.

1. consider for a case where the motion is in x direction. I created the matching points as given below where there is a movement of 50 pixels in x direction only.

**Previous Image co-ordinate**

```
 [0] {x=50.000 y=50.00 }   [1] {x=100.00 y=50.00 }
 [2] {x=150.00 y=50.00 }   [3] {x=200.00 y=50.00 }  
 [4] {x=250.00 y=50.00 }   [5] {x=300.00 y=50.00 }  
 [6] {x=50.000 y=100.0 }   [7] {x=100.00 y=100.0 }  
 [8] {x=150.00 y=100.0 }   [9] {x=200.00 y=100.0 }  
[10] {x=250.00 y=100.0 }  [11] {x=300.00 y=100.0 }  
[12] {x=50.000 y=150.0 }  [13] {x=100.00 y=150.0 }  
[14] {x=150.00 y=150.0 }  [15] {x=200.00 y=150.0 }
```

**Current Image co-ordinate**
     [0] {x=100.0 y=50.0 }  [1] {x=150.0 y=50.0 }
     [2] {x=200.0 y=50.0 }  [3] {x=250.0 y=50.0 }
     [4] {x=300.0 y=50.0 }  [5] {x=350.0 y=50.0 } 
     [6] {x=100.0 y=100. }  [7] {x=150.0 y=100. } 
     [8] {x=200.0 y=100. }  [9] {x=250.0 y=100. } 
    [10] {x=300.0 y=100. } [11] {x=350.0 y=100. }
    [12] {x=100.0 y=150. } [13] {x=150.0 y=150. } 
    [14] {x=200.0 y=150. } [15] {x=250.0 y=150. }

**Intrinsic Matrix**
    6.2821272+002      0.          3.474665e+002 
    0.     6.2886809e+002       2.4486120e+002 
    0. 0. 1.
with known Intrinsic matrix I calculated the fundamental matrix using opencv function(`cvFindFundamentalMatrix`)

```
int fm_count = cvFindFundamentalMat( pMatPtsImgPrev, pMatPtsImgCurr, 
        pFundMat,CV_FM_RANSAC ,0.2,0.99, status);
```

the average pixex error is verymuch close to zero.

then find essential matrix from using the formula given below

```
E = CameraMatrix^T * F * CameraMatrix.
```

Essential matrix with X offset
-6.227048e-030,    1.8018814e-014,  4.30140591e-015 
3.1235024e-014,    2.7432764e-015,  7.02982759
9.885755751e-015,  -7.0298275,      3.10862446e-015

Then decompose rotation and translation matrix as given in the below link using SVD - SVD decomp = SVD(E);

[Extract Translation and Rotation from Fundamental Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150152/extract-translation-and-rotation-from-fundamental-matrix)

when decomposed the rotation angles Rx =0deg Ry =0deg and Rz =0deg.

This seems to be fine as the rotation is either 0 or 180deg.

When the co-ordinate is changed with translation in y direction only as the co-ordinates given below

**Previous co-ordinate**

```
 [0] {x=50.00 y=50.00 }  [1] {x=100.0 y=50.00 }
 [2] {x=150.0 y=50.00 }   [3] {x=200.0 y=50.00 }
 [4] {x=250.0 y=50.00 }  [5] {x=300.0 y=50.00 }
 [6] {x=50.00 y=100.0 }  [7] {x=100.0 y=100.0 }
 [8] {x=150.0 y=100.0 }  [9] {x=200.0 y=100.0 }   
[10] {x=250.0 y=100.0 } [11] {x=300.0 y=100.0 }
[12] {x=50.00 y=150.0 } [13] {x=100.0 y=150.0 }
[14] {x=150.0 y=150.0 } [15] {x=200.0 y=150.0 }
```

**Current co-ordinate**

```
 [0] {x=50.00 y=100.0 }  [1] {x=100.0 y=100.0 }
 [2] {x=150.0 y=100.0 }  [3] {x=200.0 y=100.0 }
 [4] {x=250.0 y=100.0 }  [5] {x=300.0 y=100.0 }
 [6] {x=50.00 y=150.0 }  [7] {x=100.0 y=150.0 }
 [8] {x=150.0 y=150.0 }  [9] {x=200.0 y=150.0 }
[10] {x=250.0 y=150.0 } [11] {x=300.0 y=150.0 }
[12] {x=50.00 y=200.0 } [13] {x=100.0 y=200.0 }
[14] {x=150.0 y=200.0 } [15] {x=200.0 y=200.0 }
```

the same procedure and same intrinsic matrix is used to construct fundamental matrix and essential matrix.

Essential matrix with Y offset
    -2.791314e-030,     2.5449611e-015,     5.095796479e-016
    4.3544169e-015,     -0.039722588,       0.99921074
]   1.78226326e-015,    -0.999210746,       -0.03972258

but the rotation decomposed is Rx=-2.27653561deg Ry = 180, and Rz = 0

What I am not understanding is how come Rx has some value as the translation is in either X and y direction, what i feel is the rotations should be either 0 or 180deg.

Kindy give me some hint so that if there is any problem in my code.